# Drupal 7 - get variables from hook_theme

Tags: variables, drupal-7, parameter-passing, hook-theme

I tried to pass a variable from a custom module to a tpl file.
In my custom module (named example)

**1. I created a route with an argument via hook_menu :**

```
function example_menu() {
  $items['example/fancybox-photos/%'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'example_display_fancybox_photos',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      );
    return $items;
    }
```

**2. I created my page callback function :**

```
function example_display_fancybox_photos($nid) {
  $nodePhoto = node_load($nid);
  $field_photo = field_get_items('node', $nodePhoto, 'field_photo');

  $photo = [
  "field_photo" => $field_photo[0]['uri'],
  ....
  ];

  return theme('example_fancybox_photos', array('infosPhoto' => $photos));
}
```

**3 . I created a hook_theme**

```
function example_theme() {
  $themes = array();

  $themes['example_fancybox_photos'] = array(
    'template' => 'templates/example-fancybox-photos',
    'variables' => array('infosPhoto' => NULL),
  );

  return $themes;
}
```

**4 . I finally created a tpl named "example-fancybox-photos.tpl.php" in templates folder (in theme folder)**

```
<pre><?php print var_dump($infosPhoto); ?></pre>
```

The result is NULL

I did some researchs but i dont understand why the variable is still NULL.

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You have passed `$photos` but you have array as `$photo`. try to change that

Hope the below code helps you.

```
function example_menu(){
    $items['example/fancybox-photos/%'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'example_display_fancybox_photos',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );
    return $items;
}

function example_display_fancybox_photos($nid){
    $photos = 'value from example module!';
    return theme('example_fancybox_photos',array('photos' => $photos));
}

function example_theme() {
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'example');
    return array(
        'example_fancybox_photos' => array(
            'variables' => array('photos' => null),
            'template' => 'example_fancybox_photos',
            'path' => $path, 
        ),
    );
}
```

Place your tpl file example_fancybox_photos.tpl.php in your module directory and inside it use the below code.

```
<?php print $photos; ?>
```

or

```
function example_theme() {
    return array(
        'example_fancybox_photos' => array(
            'variables' => array('photos' => null),
            'template' => 'example_fancybox_photos',
        ),
    );
}
```

Place your tpl file example_fancybox_photos.tpl.php in your theme directory and inside it place the below code

```
<?php print $photos; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get the variable from the module to the tpl !

**1. I created a route with an argument via hook_menu :**

```
function example_menu() {
  $items['example/fancybox-photos/%'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'example_display_fancybox_photos',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      );
    return $items;
    }
```

**2. I created my page callback function :**

```
function example_display_fancybox_photos($nid) {
  $nodePhoto = node_load($nid);
  $field_photo = field_get_items('node', $nodePhoto, 'field_photo');

  $photos = [
  "field_photo" => $field_photo[0]['uri'],
  ....
  ];

  return theme('example_fancybox_photos', array('infosPhoto' => $photos));
}
```

**3 . I created a hook_theme**

```
function example_theme() {
  $themes = array();

  $themes['example_fancybox_photos'] = array(
    'template' => 'templates/example_fancybox_photos',
    'variables' => array('infosPhoto' => NULL),
  );

  return $themes;
}
```

**4 . I finally created a tpl named "example_fancybox_photos.tpl.php" in templates folder (in MODULE (example) folder)**

The problems were that:
- the tpl was not named in the same way and with dashes instead of underscore
- the tpl was in the template folder of the theme and not of the module